# Separate string array into columns of 32

Tags: c#, arrays, string, string-formatting

I have a string array with 96 elements. I would like the array formatted into one string like this:

```
str    str
str    str
str    str
str    str
```

instead of like this:

```
str
str
str
str
str
str
str
str
```

but with 32 in each column instead of 4.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: 32 in each column with 96 total means you want three columns?

Comment: Could you describe a general formula which, given your total number of strings, produces the number which should go in each column? Or are the numbers 96 and 32 fixed?

Comment: There should always be 32 in each column. The number of columns will be 1-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 32 "rows" and 3 "columns" you can use this LINQ query:

```
string[] strings = Enumerable.Repeat("str", 96).ToArray();
IEnumerable<string[]> arrays = strings
    .Select((str, index) => new { str, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 3)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.str).ToArray());
```

So each `string[]` contains three strings and the sequence contains 32 `string[]`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = 0;
var result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                         array.GroupBy(s => index++ / 3)
                              .Select(g => String.Join("\t", g)));
```

If you want strings to be aligned in columns, then instead of `String.Join("\t", g)` use:

```
String.Join("", g.Select(s => String.Format("{0,-20}",s)))
```

That will give each columns width of 20 characters and left-align strings in columns.

Comment: Possible to make it dynamic? There will sometimes be 32 elements, sometimes 48, etc.

Comment: @user3427376 just specify number of columns you want to have. I.e. introduce variable `int numberOfColumns = 2;` and use it in grouping statement: `GroupBy(s => index++ / numberOfColumns)`

Answer (score 0):

this may be the solution :

```
int[,] MyArray = new int[32,2];
```

now if you want to put values then :

```
MyArray[0,0] = your first value
//// until
MyArray[32,2] = your last value
```

surely you could use your desired type instead of the `int` type.